# Does ENS implement EIP-2304 yet?

Tags: ens, bug, resolver

I have registered an ENS domain: `ncwc6edqldzy6mlo.eth` (on mainnet)

It uses the default registry: `0x00000000000C2E074eC69A0dFb2997BA6C7d2e1e`

And the following public resolver: `0x4976fb03C32e5B8cfe2b6cCB31c09Ba78EBaBa41`

I have set two records for ETH and ETC using the [ENS app](https://app.ens.domains/name/ncwc6edqldzy6mlo.eth/details):

- ETH `0xde270E46D63B1816d1B798cFF473c4ba238aCa73`
- ETC `0x37287f68aC899b769FAa57033c78B78c76C68dc0`

When I query the `addr` function with the `namehash` for `ncwc6edqldzy6mlo.eth`, I get the correct result.

```ruby
infura.call(resolver, "addr", "0xfab68bf82e5750a73a16c3c157598b4be30ed6b7e048f8e29e11572119713eaa")
# => "0xde270e46d63b1816d1b798cff473c4ba238aca73"
```

The same works if I pass the coin type `60` for Ethereum according to [SLIP-44](https://github.com/satoshilabs/slips/blob/master/slip-0044.md):

```ruby
infura.call(resolver, "addr", "0xfab68bf82e5750a73a16c3c157598b4be30ed6b7e048f8e29e11572119713eaa", 60).unpack('H*').first
# => "de270e46d63b1816d1b798cff473c4ba238aca73"
```

However, I am unable to retrieve the Ethereum Classic address I have set with the coin type `61`:

```ruby
infura.call(resolver, "addr", "0xfab68bf82e5750a73a16c3c157598b4be30ed6b7e048f8e29e11572119713eaa", 61)
# => ""
```

But the ENS application shows the record. How does it store the ETC record if not using coin type 61 as per [EIP-2304](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2304)?

Comment: Really not that knowledgeable on ENS but through subgraph I could see that your ETC record is under the coin type `2147483709` , turns out that this value can be written as `0x8000003d` which happens to be the path component for Ethereum classic ( https://github.com/satoshilabs/slips/blob/master/slip-0044.md ) . I really couldn't explain why, curious if anyone has the answer it's far from what the ENS doc explains...

Comment: I created a ticket, I'm pretty sure it's a bug: https://github.com/ensdomains/ens-app/issues/1588